# How would I display uploaded photos like a stack of cards in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

On my website, the user can upload a photo and that photo's displayed on the browser (the one provided).

How do I make it so that when other users login and upload photos, then other users who decide to log in later on can see that photo as well but their only means of navigating through the photos is with a, say, `next` and `previous` button click.

In other words: How would I display uploaded photos like a stack of cards?

```
const redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit = this.state.redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit;
    const { url } = this.state;

    if (redirectToStackAfterPhotoSubmit) {
        return (
            <Stack
                imagesOnStack={url || 'http://via.placeholder.com/400x300'}
                alt="Uploaded Images"
                height="300"
                Width="400"
            />
        );
    }
```

Are there any resources online that I didn't see?  I've tried searching it, but I couldn't really find a silver bullet answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
How do I make it so that when other users login and upload photos, then other users who decide to log in later on can see that photo as well but their only means of navigating through the photos is with a, say, next and previous button click.
```

To do something like this you need to build much more than just the React-side. React is there to simply handle the rendering/creation of content to be seen by the use (The Front-end).

You'll need to look into building a full-stack application, (MERN stack).

MongoDB - the database to store said images and retrieve them.
Express - For the routing to retrieve said images
React - For the viewing of said images and its interaction with them.
Node - For the server that connects it all.

Comment: I'm using Firebase database, would that suffice?  I only say this because it has a Mongo DB type structure/style.